# Microsoft flow condition not to re trigger an email if the mail was sent earlier

Tags: sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow, power-automate, send-email

I am working on a sharepoint list where there are two dropdown columns-

1. Student to be added to Mathematics - Yes/No
2. Student to be added to Science - Yes/No

I am trying to build a Microsoft flow which will trigger an email to Mathematics department if "Yes" is selected for "Student to be added to Mathematics" and an email to Science department if "Yes" is selected for "Student to be added to Science" and I have achieved this.

Now, when I create or modify list item and have selected "Yes" for "Student to be added to Mathematics" and "No" for "Student to be added to Science", it triggers an email only to Mathematics department which is correc.

But the next time when I re-edit the list item and if "Student to be added to Mathematics" is already "Yes" it should not re-trigger the email as it has already sent it once.

Is it possible to do this by giving a condition. If yes, request you to please suggest how can this be achieved.

Thank you!

Comment: Create 2 hidden columns each for Maths and Science and set their values to Yes when you first time send an email ( Set Default to No) .  Compare if this column value is No and your column value Is Yes, then only send an email.

Comment: Do you want to send an email notification only when item is created? What if "Student to be added to Mathematics" is "No" when item is created and "Student to be added to Mathematics" is set to "Yes" when item is modified, do you want to send an email for such cases or not?

Comment: Hello Ganesh, Thank you for your response. Even if the "Student to be added to Mathematics" is "No" when created and then later on modified it to "Yes" then it should trigger an email but once when the "Student to be added to Mathematics" is set to "Yes" and the mail is triggered,next time when the user sets "Student to be added to Science" as "Yes" and doesn't change "Student to be added to Science" as "No", it should only send email for Science and not Mathematics as mail for Mathematics has already been sent once.

Comment: Hello Diksha, Thank you for your response. Is it possible for you to elaborate your solution. I will try to work on it and check if it works.. :)

Comment: Also, I would like to mention that the mails which are triggered as of now are done using microsoft flow where I have put a condition if "Student to be added to Mathematics" is set to "Yes" then send an email.